# Clear the file stat cache in R?

Tags: r

In a RUnit test I have this snippet:

```
checkTrue(!file.exists(fname))
doSomething()
#cat(fname);print(file.info(fname))
checkTrue(file.exists(fname))
```

The second call to checkTrue() is failing, even though `doSomething()` creates a file. I've confirmed the file is there with the commented out line, shown above.

So, I'm wondering if the second call to `file.exists` is using cached data? In PHP there is a function called `clearstatcache` that stops this happening. Is there an R equivalent? (Or, perhaps, someone knows that R never caches results of stat calls?)

Comment: I have tried with `fname <- 'test123.txt'` and `doSomething <- function() write.table(cars, file = fname)`: both `checkTrue` calls return `TRUE`. Please give us more details and make your example reproducible.

Comment: Also, if you are advanced enough to create unit tests, shouldn't your `doSomething` function take `fname` as an argument, rather than use it as a global variable?

Comment: Thanks for the check @flodel. My question is about clearing the stat cache of `file.exists`, as a tool for troubleshooting my code; not really about how to write unit tests.  If clearing stat cache doesn't help, and I'm out of ideas, I'll come back with a reproducible example. (Incidentally `doSomething` is creating the filename from data; the unit test is testing it is making the expected filename, among other things!)

Comment: well, what I was hinting towards is that maybe `file.exists` does not use cached data, but that you did something wrong. I'll be happy to be proven wrong, but for that you will need to provide us with a reproducible example.

Comment: @flodel I realized it must have been tagging my question as "runit" that caused the confusion (I also *wasn't* asking why my second call to file.exists returns false; I was asking if there is an R equivalent to clearstatcache.) Anyway, I downloaded the source and managed to self-answer.

Answer (score 2):

`file.exists` does not cache the result of the stat call, so there is no equivalent of PHP's `clearstatcache`. (Aside: that also means excessive use of calling `file.exists`, or any `stat` function, might degrade performance.)

As of R 3.0.1, `file.exists` uses an internal method. If you follow it through the source you will eventually end up with a call to `R_FileExists`, in sysutils.c:

```
Rboolean R_FileExists(const char *path)
{
    struct stat sb;
    return stat(R_ExpandFileName(path), &sb) == 0;
}
```

(On Windows it instead uses a call to [_stat64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) which I've just confirmed also does not do caching.)